# jQuery: Not getting JSON response from an affiliate service

Tags: jquery, json

Same url works fine on browser. I tried with `dataType:jsonp` but no luck. Error logs say `error, error, <empty>` in same order.

**Code**

```
var url="http://api-product.skimlinks.com/categories?key=hide&format=json";
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
          type:"GET",
          dataType: "json",
          url: url,
          success:function(data){
            alert(data);
          },
          error:function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(xhr.statusText);
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        });
     });
```

Comment: The browser is probably blocking the request. Does that service support JSONP?

Comment: Check the network tab of your browser's dev tools.

Comment: How would I know if browser is blocking it? No that service doesn't support JSONP. I read somewhere using it for `cross-domain` error.

Comment: @JasonP On Network tab I do see `failed` request for given URL.

Comment: What's the error or response? I'm assuming it's a cross domain issue. Like Blender said, look into whether the service supports JSONP.